# Stacking small polygons inside another bigger one

Tags: python, polygon, shapely

I have the following shapely pixel polygon

```
big_poly = Polygon([(94.5, 77.0),
                    (92.5, 53.0),
                    (87.5, 45.0),
                    (66.0, 20.5),
                    (9.0, 3.5),
                    (5.5, 6.0),
                    (4.5, 13.0),
                    (7.5, 26.0),
                    (6.5, 91.0),
                    (8.0, 92.5),
                    (16.0, 92.5),
                    (44.0, 86.5)])
```

I need to fill the `big_poly` with 4 by 6, pixel polygons, have them all fall within the border of the big one and parallel to its min axis (same rotation).

The solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399749/get-all-lattice-points-lying-inside-a-shapely-polygon) sure were helpful thanks to @Georgy.
So I was able to do the following:

[image]

with the following code:

```
b = building_poly.boundary
points = []
for x in range(int(np.floor(xmin)), int(np.ceil(xmax)), 4):
for y in range(int(np.floor(ymin)), int(np.ceil(ymax)), 6):
points.append((x, y))
points = MultiPoint(points)
result = points.intersection(building_poly)
```

And plotting the points in `result`, but now I need to create polygons from these points.
How can I turn these points into rectangular polygons?

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63876018/cut-a-shapely-polygon-into-n-equally-sized-polygons), but not sure how to make it fit my case.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Get all lattice points lying inside a Shapely polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44399749/7851470). Maybe you could adapt it to your case.

Comment: Thanks! this helped me a lot, but could you please check the updates in my question. Even though I had a better idea now, still I'm not clear on how to get the result I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what we could do:

1. Construct two arrays of X and Y coordinates based on the boundaries of the given polygon
2. Construct a grid of rectangles covering completely the given polygon by iterating over the consecutive pairs of X and Y coordinates
3. Filter out those rectangles that don't lie completely inside the polygon

This is, most probably, not the most efficient solution, but it performs well for your case:

```
dx = 4
dy = 6
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = big_poly.bounds
xs = np.arange(np.floor(xmin), np.ceil(xmax) + 1, dx) 
ys = np.arange(np.floor(ymin), np.ceil(ymax) + 1, dy)
rectangles = (Polygon([(x_start, y_start), (x_end, y_start), 
                       (x_end, y_end), (x_start, y_end)])
              for x_start, x_end in zip(xs, xs[1:])
              for y_start, y_end in zip(ys, ys[1:]))
rectangles = [rectangle for rectangle in rectangles 
              if big_poly.contains(rectangle)]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This looks beautiful!